# В чем смысл ограничивать универсальный тип в обобщенном класе?

Tags: c#, generics

В чем разница между

```
class Transaction<T> where T: Account
{
    public T FromAccount { get; set; } 
}
```

и

```
class Transaction
{
    public Account FromAccount { get; set; } 
}
```

?

**UPD**
Резюмируя ответы и комментарии: смысла использовать дженерик с ограничением в один класс нет. В этом случае дженерик схлопывается в обычный класс.
Смысл появляется, если указывать некие более общие ограничивающие параметры - например, интерфейс, который должен реализовывать универсальный тип.

Comment: В классах-наследниках класса Transaction, которые как параметр будут использовать наследников класса Account

Comment: Если общий класс не ограничить, то T окажется фактически типом `object`, а вот с конкретным типом уже можно работать - присваивать и читать свойства, вызывать методы. По поводу разницы - тут обычная разница обобщенного класса и любого другого - никакой копипасты. Понадобится вам `Transaction` от другого класса - не придётся писать новый класс.

Comment: @Monk, но если мне понадобится Transaction от другого класса, я не смогу его создать - мне помешает ограничение, не так ли?

Comment: В целом - да. Поэтому если у вас только один тип может работать с этим классом (и в дальнейшем новых не планируется), то никакого смысла в обобщенном классе нет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если ты ограничиваешь универсальный тип, то он становится более предсказуемым.

Как следствие, ты можешь проделать дополнительные вещи:

1. Если ты ограничивает тип тем, что он должен обязательно иметь конструктор без параметров, то ты сможешь создавать экземпляр типа использовав оператор `new`
2. Если ты ограничиваешь тип тем, что он должен быть наследником определенного класса, то у тебя пропадает необходимость того, что внутри ты должен выполнять дополнительные проверки и более того, методы того базового класса будут доступны в методе без рефлексии и intellisense будет их тебе подсвечивать
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. Если класс параметр ограничен, как `ValueType`, то мы можем сравнивать все через оператор `=` не беспокоясь о том, что будет некорректное сравнение, так как значимые типы сравнивают по значению
4. Собственно, если вы укажите ограничения, то уже на этапе компиляции словите ошибку, попытаясь передать что-то не то в метод. Например, вы ожидаете значимый тип, а передаете объект. Если бы вы использовали object, то вам бы пришлось в этом случае внутри выполнять проверки через рефлексию + просадок производительности из-за упаковки/распаковки.
5. Код становится самодокументированным. Если пользователь вашего типа передаст в метод то, чего вы не ожидаете, то он сразу же об этом узнает и ничего скомпилировано не будет. Однако, например, если бы вы ожидали тип, который имеет конструктор по умолчанию, а по факту его не было бы, то при подходе без дженериков ваш бы метод молча съел бы тип, который не соответствует требованиям, а пользователь получил ошибку в рантайме.

Если универсальный тип не имеет никаких ограничений, то тип не чем не лучше в плане взаимодействия `object'а` (если отбросить + в отсутствии упаковки значимого типа). В некоторых случаях этого нам достаточно, например в `List<T>` нету никаких ограничений, но когда мы хотим сделать над ним какие-то доп. специфические действия, то без ограничений приходится делать дополнительные телодвижения...

Comment: но то же самое можно делать, если не использовать обобщенный тип. Вопрос именно в том, в чем же смысл накладывать _ограничеие_ на _обобщение_. Например, смысл обобщения для коллекции понятен. Но зачем накладывать ограничение на обобщение коллекции?

Comment: Если второй пункт вы еще как-то сможете сделать не используя обобщенный тип указав в качестве аргумента базовый тип, то 1 и 3 придется вам делать через дорогую рефлексию.

Comment: Еще 4 пункт добавил.

Comment: 1п. - в моем примере, что мешает в классе без генерика использовать `new Account()`? 3п. - то же самое ,что мешает сравнивать объекты одного класса?

Comment: Ничего. Но смысл в том, что дженерики созданы для того, что бы выполнять схожую логику над большим числом типов. Благодаря дженерикам у нас нету ListInt,ListFloat ... и т д. В вашем случае, если вы захотите делать фабричный метод, то вам придется на кадлый тип делать свой метод. А с дженериком вы можете один раз все описать и не дублирвоать код.

Comment: Про смысл дженериков я знаю, но вот смысл _ограничений_ на дженерики меня просто ставит в тупик. Я спрашивал об этом человека, который всю иерархию данных проекта построил на дженериках с ограничениями, получил примерно те же ответы. Но мы попробовали ради эксперимента переписать код на обычные типы, перенеся функции ограничений на интерфейсы и наследование и получилось то же самое по результату. Может быть, немного пострадала читаемость.

Comment: По пункту 3. Вы не можете сравнить ссылочные типы. Обычно, сравнение по ссылке- это не желаемое поведение. Благодаря дженерикам, вы можете повесить ограничение, что классы должны реализовывать интерфейс IComparable. В противном случае вам бы пришлось эти проверки выполнять внутри метода через рефлексию. А так у пользователя данного метода сразу же вылетит ошибка компиляции, которая бы не вылетела в случае без дженериков.

Comment: Ну и касательно того, что вы смогли переписать код с дженериками к виду без дженериков: В программировании одну задачу можно решить разными способами => решайте задачу так, как вам удобно.

Comment: @DmitryMalikov по поводу `new Account()`. В этом примере и проблема: в вашем классе без дженериков вы сможете создавать новые экземпляры *только* данного класса. Можно конечно начинать писать всякие условные операторы, но сами понимаете какой это треш будет. А если класс Account будет абстрактным, то вы вообще не сможете создавать его экземпляры, поэтому тут и удобство дженериков. Написав `where T : Account, new()` вы всегда будете гарантировать, что данный класс будет работать с любым наследником Account, имеющий конструктор без параметров.

Comment: @John, так я о чем и говор - в классе без дженериков ровно тот же функционал, что и в классе с дженериком, ограниченном ровно одним классом. Я попробовал перебрать варианты https://dotnetfiddle.net/aStJhy - никаких противоречий не заметил. Про полезность дженериков и ограничений дописал в UPD.

Comment: @DmitryMalikov если у вас ровно один *конкретный* класс используется без намека на его наследников, то почему у вас вообще возникает вопрос о дженериках?) Почему-то, когда вы создаёте класс с string'овым полем у вас не возникает вопрос, почему бы его не сделать дженериком?)

Comment: @John не знаю, вон мне все выше пишут, что в классе без дженериков я могу использовать только Account. Но вообще-то нет, я могу использовать и его наследников без всяких дженериков. Вопрос-то был про конкретную реализацию, ту, которую я привел в вопросе.

Comment: @DmitryMalikov если просто использовать, то да, но не создавать новые экземпляры. А если про конкретно твой случай, то просто взгляни на то, какого типа будет твое свойство FromAccount. Без дженериков всегда будет Account. Установить не проблема наследником, а вернуть только через преобразование. С дженериком такой проблемы не будет, ты уже в коде выставишь конкретный подтип. Как уже сказали - это всё не обязательно делать. Делай без дженериков, если хочется. Просто дженерики позволяют сделать код максимально универсальным.